# SQL: Insert DateCreated value?

Tags: php, sql, datetime

In my table I have a dateCreated column in the format of DATETIME.

How do I insert the current datetime when I add the record to the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better use `TIMESTAMP` instead and use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to get current timestamp. `TIMESTAMP` should behave exaclty (or very similar) to `DATETIME` so you shouldn't notice a difference.

Furthermore you may set `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default for all new entries.

Comment: +1: For CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, because it's ANSI standard & supported on Oracle, SQL Server, Postgres, MySQL...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CURDATETIME()`

Comment: We don't know the database - see my comment on nikic's answer